# Pandas/pyplot coloring scatter plot points by condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Good time of day everyone! I'm working on a simple script for quality analysis that compares original and duplicate samples and plots those on a scatter plot.

So far I've been able to create plots that I need:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''read file'''

duplicates_file = 'C:/Users/cherp2/Desktop/duplicates.csv'
duplicates = pd.read_csv(
            duplicates_file, usecols=['SAMPLE_NUMBER','Duplicate Sample Type'
                                      ,'FE', 'P','SIO2','AL2O3'
                                      ,'Orig. Sample Type', 'FE.1', 'P.1'
                                      ,'SIO2.1','AL2O3.1'])

'''calculate standard deviations for grades'''

grades = ['FE','P','SIO2','AL2O3']

for grade in grades:
    grade_std = duplicates[grade].std()

    '''create scatter plots for all grades'''

    ax = duplicates.plot.scatter(f'{grade}', f'{grade}.1')
    ax.set_xlabel('Original sample')
    ax.set_ylabel('Duplicate sample')
```

but now I want to color plot points by a condition: if a grade difference between the original and duplicate sample is less than one standard deviation point should be in green, if it's between 2 and 3 stdev it should be orange and red if more than that.

I've been trying to find solutions online but so far nothing has worked. I have a feeling that I'd need to use some lambda function here, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a color argument to the plotting call (via `c=`) and using `pandas.cut` to generate the necessary color code for different categories based on std.

```
In [227]: df
Out[227]: 
           a         b
0   0.991415 -0.627043
1   1.365594 -0.036651
2  -0.376318 -0.536504
3   1.041561 -2.180642
4   1.017692 -0.308826
5  -0.626566  1.613980
6  -1.302070  1.258944
7  -0.453499  0.411277
8  -0.927880  0.439102
9  -0.282031  1.249862
10  0.504829  0.536641
11 -1.528550  1.420456
12  0.774111 -1.086350
13 -1.662715  0.732753
14 -1.038514 -1.987912
15 -0.432515  3.104590
16  1.682876  0.663448
17  0.287642 -1.038507
18 -0.307923 -2.340498
19 -1.024045 -1.948608

In [228]: change = df.a - df.b

In [229]: df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='b',
                  c=pd.cut(((change - change.mean()) / (change.std())).abs(), [0, 1, 2, 3], labels=['r', 'g', 'b']))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! `pd.cut()` definitely should help. Only thing is I couldn't get it work exactly as you had in your example. Instead, I modified my `for` cycle and created grade bins for all the categories. Now I'm trying to get the color coding to work but I keep getting syntax errors when I finally try and create a plot: `axs[0,1].scatter(duplicates[f'{grade}'], duplicates[f'{grade}.1'],
           c=(duplicates[f'{grade}_bins'], labels=['r','g','b']))` What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @user2825403, without seeing your data, I am guess the `c=` part should be `c=pd.cut(duplicates[f'{grade}_bins'], labels=['r','g','b'])` ?